# UPDATE not working properly with linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the query below:

```
select thisdate,created from dbusns d
INNER JOIN (SELECT  MAX(created) created,
                    C.reference 
            FROM dbusns
            INNER JOIN [server].CUSTODYDB.DBO.dbcustody C
                ON dbusnS.urns = C.reference
            WHERE dbusns.datasetname = 'CUSTODY'
            GROUP BY C.reference) T on D.urns = T.reference
WHERE D.urns = '1'
```

This returns: 2008-10-31 00:00:00.000, 2008-11-01 00:00:00.000

I then run the query below:

```
UPDATE D
SET thisdate = T.created
FROM dbusns D
INNER JOIN (SELECT  MAX(created) created,
                    C.reference 
            FROM dbusns
            INNER JOIN [server].CUSTODYDB.DBO.dbcustody C
                ON dbusnS.urns = C.reference
            WHERE dbusns.datasetname = 'CUSTODY'
            GROUP BY C.reference) T on D.urns = T.reference
WHERE D.urns = '1'
```

I then run the query below, which returns: 2008-10-31 00:00:00.000 (it should be: 2008-11-01 00:00:00.000)

```
select THISDATE from dbusns where datasetname='CUSTODY' AND URNS='1'
```

Created and ThisDate are datetimes.  If I reduce the number of records in dbcustody to 29,598 then the value updates correctly.  I tried deleting the 29,598th record but this did not work.

What is going on? It appears to be the execution plan that is incorrect as the remote query it is sending is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 created FROM dbcustody where reference='1'
```

Why is not sending a MAX statement/ORDER BY created desc?

Comment: Are both servers using the same collation and are both `dbcustody` and `busns` tables or is one/both of them a view?

Comment: @Dommer, They are both the same server.  They both have the same collation.

Comment: If they are the same server why are you using a four part query? I'm confused. Or do you mean they are using the same version of SQL? But what about the collation of each database? And is either a view rather than a table?

Comment: @Dommer, sorry they are on different servers.  Both tables, same collation.

Comment: Cool, okay, what about trying `OPENQUERY` instead? I will edit my answer with an example...

Comment: Does the update report rows updated = 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT: Removed some irrelevant stuff.*

When this has happened to me in the past, I have usually resorted to [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188427.aspx) which tends to solve the issue. Try this:

```
UPDATE D
SET thisdate = T.created
FROM dbusns D
INNER JOIN (SELECT MaxCreated, Reference FROM OPENQUERY(server, 'SELECT MAX(created) MaxCreated, reference
    FROM CUSTODYDB.DBO.dbcustody') as RemoteTable
    INNER JOIN dbusns ON dbusnS.urns = RemoteTable.reference
    WHERE dbusns.datasetname = 'CUSTODY'
    GROUP BY RemoteTable.reference) T ON D.urns = T.reference
WHERE D.urns = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get: 2008-10-31 00:00:00.000 2008-11-01 00:00:00.000 when I execute your query above.  It is the execution plan that is wrong (see the remote query in my OP - the last SQL statement).

Comment: Yeah, I think I misread the original question. My answer is not right!

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I would always fully qualify each column e,g, `d.thisdate` rather than `thisdate` and also change the name of a max column (so call it `maxCreated` instead of `created`, just to remove any ambiguity. This might help to see what's going on.

Comment: OPENQUERY is a solution i.e. the correct date is updated (the execution plan is also correct).  Do you know why this is the case? +1.

Comment: That's great! I don't know exactly why it didn't work before, but I have had this problem myself in the past and `OPENQUERY` usually fixes it. Maybe we can find a SQL expert to tell us and then update the answer. Speaking of which, let me tidy up the answer a bit to make it more useful to other people before it's accepted.

Comment: Thanks.  I have accepted the answer.  I am going to ask another question.