# OPENQUERY retrieves the correct value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see a question I asked here earlier: [UPDATE not working properly with linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324823/update-not-working-properly-with-linked-server/24325381?noredirect=1#24325381)

Dommer suggested using OPENQUERY and this does appear to resolve the problem.  Does anyone know why OPENQUERY resolves the problem?  I have read the documentation for OPENQUERY here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188427.aspx, but I have not found an answer to my specific question.

Comment: I think this question may be more appropriate for DBA stackexchange so have voted to close.